# Spring ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a use case where I need to return a PDF to a user which is generated for us.  It seems that what I need to do is utilize the ResponseEntity in this case, but I have a couple of things which are not very clear.

1. How can I redirect the user -- let's pretend they don't have the permissions to access this page?  How can I redirect them to a separate controller?
2. Am I able to set the response encoding?
3. Can I achieve either of these two without bringing in the HttpResponse as a parameter to my RequestMapping?

I'm using Spring 3.0.5.  Example code below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/generate/data/pdf.xhtml")
public class PdfController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<byte []> generatePdf(@RequestAttribute("key") Key itemKey) {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));

        if (itemKey == null || !allowedToViewPdf(itemKey)) {
            //How can I redirect here?
        }

        //How can I set the response content type to UTF_8 -- I need this
        //for a separate controller
        return new ResponseEntity<byte []>(PdfGenerator.generateFromKey(itemKey),
                                           responseHeaders,
                                           HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

I'd really like to not pull in the Response... None of my controllers have done so thus far, and I'd hate to have to bring it in at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dealing with redirecting (these are instances which we open in new windows / tabs) anyhow we decided to just display the error message they would have received.

This likely won't work for all, but with the way we add error / status messages we were unable to get those messages to persist on the view upon exception occurring.

Answer (score 25):

Note, this works in Spring 3.1, not sure about spring 3.0.5 as asked in the original question.

In your return ResponseEntity statement where you want to handle the redirect, just add in a "Location" header to the ResponseEntity, set the body to null and set the HttpStatus to FOUND (302).

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Location", "http://stackoverflow.com");

return new ResponseEntity<byte []>(null,headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

This will keep you from having to change the return type of the controller method.

Comment: `HttpHeaders` contains type-safe helper methods, so `headers.setLocation(uri)` would be saner.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the redirect, all you need to do is change the return type to Object:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/generate/data/pdf.xhtml")
public class PdfController {

    @RequestMapping
    public Object generatePdf(@RequestAttribute("key") Key itemKey) {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));

        if (itemKey == null || !allowedToViewPdf(itemKey)) {
            return "redirect:/some/path/to/redirect"
        }

        //How can I set the response content type to UTF_8 -- I need this
        //for a separate controller
        return new ResponseEntity<byte []>(PdfGenerator.generateFromKey(itemKey),
                                           responseHeaders,
                                           HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirects are easy - for your handler method's return String, just prepend with `redirect:`, as in `return "redirect:somewhere else"`.

Not sure why you're objecting to the `Response` object.  Is there a reason?  Otherwise, if you just stream the PDF as an `OutputStream` on the `HttpServletResponse` object, then you don't actually need to return the PDF from your handler method - you just need to set the PDF stream on the response, which you can add to your handler method's signature.  See http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetImage.html for an example.

Comment: The biggest issue is we make use of a couple of custom interceptors to automatically add things back onto the request.  We need these interceptors to run when the user is unable to view the page to display error messages appropriately -- returning the simple redirect String doesn't get this to happen.

Comment: If you're using Interceptors, if you implement the `HandlerInterceptor`, then you have direct access to the `beforeHandle`, `afterCompletion`, and `postHandle` Controller lifecycle events, *and* you have direct access to the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects there.  Are you implementing that interface already?

Comment: These handlers are not run when you encounter an uncaught exception in your code.

Comment: Have you looked at ExceptionHandlers (I'm not sure if they fire as you need)?  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Comment: Right, but those custom exception handlers do not go through the interceptor phase (afterCompletion or postHandle).  It is simply skipped.  Thus my error messages are not placed onto the request for me.

Comment: Maybe have your handler methods throw a custom `Exception` which extends base `Exception`, and then have an `@ExceptionHandler` for that custom exception in your Controller.  Since the exception handler functions like regular handler methods, maybe it would fire your interceptors' `postHandle` after handling the exception?