# How to log security access audits

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following spring security configuration:

```
 <security:http>
   ......
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/**"  access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
   ......... 
</security:http>
```

I would like to log every case when "ROLE_ADMIN" user hits any of "/auth/**" URL pattern.

Can I put some kind of interceptor on this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do the same thing.  Use an `@Aspect` which fires for every execution of a handler method in your `/auth/`  controller.  Annotate the class as a `@Component` so its a Spring bean, add the `AspectJ` `@Aspect` annotation, and you can then inspect the `JoinPoint` for whatever the user is doing - method signature, objects, etc.  Write whatever you find to an audit table.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/aop.html for full details.  I would think a `@Before` or `@After` would work for your purposes.

Comment: yes I'm familiar with SPRING AOP and I understand that I can use it, but I just wonder if I can use some kind of interceptor to solve it.

Comment: Just addressed the interceptor question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781396/spring-responseentity/6783872#comment-8096826