# How to use spring redirect if controller method returns ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I want to write something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/member/uploadExternalImage",
            "/member/uploadExternalImage" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url,@RequestParam String fileName, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        ...
        return new ResponseEntity("Cannot save file " + fileName, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        ...
        return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
    }
```

expected behaviour - redirect to the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/member/createCompany/uploadImage",
            "/member/uploadImage" })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@Validated MultipartFileWrapper file,
            BindingResult result, Principal principal
```

But I cannot write it because `"redirect:/member/uploadImage"` is String but should be `ResponseEntity`

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: declaring `public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url,@RequestParam String fileName, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)` does not allow you to redirect?

Comment: @Jordi Castilla I need return http code

Comment: check my answer and linked one... think it will do the work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring controller method return values are just sugar when you want the output from the controller to be post processed by Spring machinery. If I have correctly understood what you are doing, you have only 2 possibilities:

- send an error response with code 500 and message `"Cannot save file " + fileName`
- redirect to `/member/uploadImage` in the same application context.

As Spring provides more goodies for redirect than for `SendError`, my advice would be to have you method return a string:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/member/uploadExternalImage",
            "/member/uploadExternalImage" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url, @RequestParam String fileName,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        ...
        //return new ResponseEntity("Cannot save file " + fileName, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            "Cannot save file " + fileName); // explicitely put error message in request
        return null;  // return null to inform Spring that response has already be processed
        ...
        return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
    }
```

Comment: can you advise something here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101800/multiple-try-catch-inside-single-method

Answer (score 38):

If you don't explicity need to return a `ResponseEntity` you can redeclare your method like:

```
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url,@RequestParam String fileName, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    return "Cannot save file " + fileName;
    ...
    return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
}
```

But if you need to use `ResponseEntity`, then it seems you can add a redirect to `ResponseEntity` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259403/3850595).

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Location", "/member/uploadImage");    
return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

Comment: Which meaning of **HttpStatus.FOUND** in your second case ?

Comment: is another value of the class [`HttpStatus`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#FOUND) code 302 (found), like when you return `HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` is a code 500 (Internal ServerError)

Comment: I need server redirect.

Comment: I can bet it can be adapted to local redirect, check second option of [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) and also [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/82309-rest-responseentity-and-custom-httpheaders) Spring forums posts,

Comment: `HttpHeaders.LOCATION` is available. Or use `headers.setLocation`.

Answer (score 6):

This could be done using the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/member/uploadExternalImage", "/member/uploadExternalImage" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url, @RequestParam String fileName,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws FileUploadException {
    ...
    throw new FileUploadException("Cannot save file " + fileName);
    ...
    return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
}

@ExceptionHandler(FileUploadException.class)
ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUploadError(final FileUploadException e) {
  return new ResponseEntity(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

In order for Spring to handle the error in your `@ExceptionHandler` method, it's required that you have the `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` exception resolver enabled. However, if you haven't specified any custom exception resolvers it will be enabled by default.