# Spring ResponseEntity and forward

Tags: spring, forwarding

Im a SpringBoot application have a REST controller that handles several cases and one of these cases it must forward to another controller.

```
@PutMapping(
        value = "/rest/endpoint",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<CustomObject> doPut(@RequestBody myDataToBeHandled) {

   if(caseAHolds(myDataToBeHandled){
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
   }
   else if(caseBHolds(myDataToBeHandled){
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   else if(caseCHolds(myDataToBeHandled){
     // Redirect here
   }

}
```

I have seen [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259403/3850595) on how to do this for a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Location` header as shown below in order to redirect the request to another URL as shown below:

```
@PutMapping(
        value = "/rest/endpoint",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<CustomObject> doPut(@RequestBody myDataToBeHandled) {

   if(caseAHolds(myDataToBeHandled){
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
   }
   else if(caseBHolds(myDataToBeHandled){
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   else if(caseCHolds(myDataToBeHandled){
     // Redirect here
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.add("Location", "ADD_URL_HERE");
     return new ResponseEntity<CustomObject>(headers, HttpStatus. OK);
   }
}
```

Comment: It should work but according to specification the request header Location should come with one of 3XX status:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location ie 302 FOUND:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and not 200 OK