# Forward with Spring ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, forwarding

Using Spring Boot (2.3.1) Rest Controller. And I have to forward to external URL.

I've found some solution here:[Spring ResponseEntity and forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033790/spring-responseentity-and-forward). And trying this:

```
  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> getHtmlReport() {
  //.....some code here
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setLocation(URI.create(url));
  return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
}
```

But it's not a **forward** - it's a **redirect**.

So how to make a **forward** with Spring ResponseEntity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring forward with added parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585216/spring-forward-with-added-parameters)

Comment: I guess no, because it's for MVC.